# Why we used the sum in the code for the gradient of the bias and why we didn't in the code of `the weight?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient, derivative, mean-square-error

The code of the partial derivatives of the mean square error:

```
w_grad = -(2 / n_samples)*(X.T.dot(y_true - y_pred))
b_grad = -(2 / n_samples)*np.sum(y_true - y_pred)
```

With `n_samples` as n, the samples number, `y_true` as the observations and `y_pred` as the predictions

My question is, why we used the sum for the gradient in the code of b (`b_grad`), and why we didn't in the code of `w_grad`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original equation is:

[image]

If you have ten features, then you have ten `W`s and ten `B`s, and the total number of variables are twenty.

But we can just sum all `B_i` into one variable, and the total number of variables becomes 10+1 = 11. It is done by adding one more dimension and fixing the last `x` be 1. The calculation becomes below:

[image]